# PhoneGap Android : navigator.notification.alert does not show up

Tags: cordova

My problem is the alert is never shown on  `navigator.notification.alert` ... but it is shown when I do `window.alert`...

Please see the code below :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Empty
    }
    function myFunction()
    {
       /* navigator.notification.alert(
                'You are the winner!',  // message
                alertDismissed,         // callback
                'Game Over',            // title
                'Done'                  // buttonName
        );*/             // NOT WORKING
        window.alert  ('Hello World!') ; // WORKS !!

    }
</script>
</head>
   <body>
   <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: call the function from onDeviceReady() i.e after the device has loaded properly.

Comment: how and where can I know whether the device is loaded or not ??

Comment: you have already written the callback for device ready event as onDeviceReady(). Inside that function, call myFunction();

Comment: Yeah.. But its not working !!

Comment: does alertDismissed function name exists in your code?

Comment: yes.. i did it..but still doesn't work !!.. also, I put plugins in config.xml and all the permissions . Still doesn't work . >_<

Comment: Just checking, but you are uncommenting the call to navigator.notification.alert, right? and did you install the notification plugin like @blackfizz mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you put

```
   <plugin name="Notification" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification"/>
```

in app/res/xml/config.xml ??

Answer (score 2):

To use the notifications, you have to install the notification plugin.
Navigate in your phonegap root directory und type:

```
phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-dialogs.git
```

From now on, you should be able to use the notification alert. :)

Comment: yes.. the plugin was missing. I put it in config.xml . Thanks